# How to use relative-path-parameter with Spring Boot/picocli executable jar?

Tags: spring-boot, relative-path, executable-jar, picocli

I have a command line application, which uses Spring Boot and picocli.
It is possible to pass parameter, which is a path, e.g. `myApp.jar /path/to/file` and it will do something with this file.
I want to use this app system-wide, so I placed the executable `.jar` in `/usr/bin/` and renamed it to `myApp`.

Now, when I use it with absolute path: `myApp /home/user/file` it works fine, but I want to pass relative path, e.g. when I am in `/home/user/` I want it to be `myApp ./file`.
The problem is that with relative path it tries to use `/usr/bin/file` instead of `/home/user/file`.

The workaround I use currently is something like this: `myApp $(pwd)/file`.

Do you have some idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so I've managed to resolve the issue by using [custom launch script for Spring Boot](https://andreas-falk.de/blog/custom-spring-boot-launch-script/)

I've copied [original sources](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/master/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-tools/spring-boot-loader-tools/src/main/resources/org/springframework/boot/loader/tools/launch.script) and removed lines responsible for working directory change:

```
run() {
  pushd "$(dirname "$jarfile")" > /dev/null # <-- removed
  "$javaexe" "${arguments[@]}"
  result=$?
  popd > /dev/null # <-- removed
  return "$result"
}
```

I am not very happy with this solution, but it is better than nothing.